# Create photo gallery using flexbox and flex items

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I stretch content inside the flex item to reach to the border of the container? For example, I am going to create family photo gallery using flexbox. But some images is not stretched to the bottom of the container?

I used this webpage https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_image_gallery.
But some images are short, not stretched till the bottom of the container.

Comment: can you provide the code and the result you are getting through it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sure, how can I provide my code?